# choose between df and du in linux

Tags: linux, du

I need to check the used space in some folders, and I need it to be fast to check because it will be inside a script.

Which command should I use, "du -h" or "df -h"??

Answer (score 3):

Well, they don't do the same thing, so it's a fairly easy choice!  `df` reports file-system usage.  `du` reports usage for directories.

Answer (score 2):

You want `du` as it gives you the space used by specific files and/or folder(s). `df` is used for checking the space used on entire filesystems.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly the answer is du, as the prior respondents stated.  If you want to specify the exact directories you're interested in and only want a summary for each then you would use:

```
du -hs /path/to/dir1
du -hs /path/to/dir2
etc
```

Answer (score 0):

`df` reports on file systems, `du` measures directory contents.

Based on your requirements, use: `du -h`

Comment: Ok, but du still takes a lot of time to finish. Is there any way to check the space used in less time than du?

Comment: I don't think `du` can be sped up; it depends on the directory tree you're trying to check. Depending on what your actual requirements are, doing a `find` for files larger than a specific size may be more appropriate?

Comment: I can't exclude files because I try to get the used space for a hosting, so it must include everything. So, in large hostings, it takes too long and the method returns an Internal Timeout.

Comment: If speed is really a need, make your directory a mount point for a separate file system.